# Disable ForwardX11Timeout without ForwardX11Trusted in OpenSSH Client?

Tags: ssh, x11, openssh

By default, recent versions of OpenSSH automatically set `ForwardX11Timeout` to 20 minutes if you set `ForwardX11Trusted` to no.

This means that 20 minutes after you start your ssh connection, you can't open any more X clients, because the authentication token has expired. Especially bad if you try to use this with long-lived connections and `ControlMaster`.

I've tried disabling by setting to 0 (does not work, causes instant expiration) and by setting to a really long value (do *not* do this, it will crash your X server. Limit is somewhere between 3 and 4 weeks).

How can I completely disable the timeout?

Comment: Judging by source it seems to be unimplemented feature in OpenSSH. In which case the right way is to [ask upstreams](https://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2014-January/031943.html). As for the crashing X server - that seems to be a bug therein.

Comment: @peterph Feel free to post as an answer. "No, you can't" definitely answers the question... Yeah, I know the X thing is a bug in the server, its already reported. Probably. Xorg has the bug marked secret.

Comment: Is the secret thing real? I thought your were joking in the chatroom.

Comment: @slm not a joke, it appears to be https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=27134 ... that bug is secret. Normally that'd be used for a undisclosed security issue. But that doesn't appear to be the case here, so I'm not sure why its secret.

Comment: @derobert crashes are often treated ass security problems unless proven otherwise, since There is often something more sinister lurking behind it (no matter how ridiculous the requirements for anything more severe than crashing your own workspace might be).

Comment: @peterph That may be, but normally you'd not if the issue was already discussed on your mailing list, a patch posted, shipped in Ubuntu, and referenced on Launchpad (plop *27134 xorg* into Google). But its of course possible that they found a deeper issue, and are working on that.

Comment: Maybe X proxying (e.g. with xpra) could be a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was [a patch 2018-04](https://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2018-April/036886.html) and [discussion 2018-06](https://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2018-June/036996.html) but my search of [mailing list archive](https://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/) by subject lines alone suggests it was not yet accepted as of 2019-04.

Duplicating some related info I posted at https://superuser.com/a/1429080/1027014 just now -

> The maximum timeout is uint_max of milliseconds minus some slack, just over 24 days.  OpenSSH_7.4p1 will accept `ssh -o ForwardX11Timeout=2147423s -X ...` which is the best answer I can make now.  ForwardX11Timeout above this may crash the XServer in some version combinations.
>
> On MacOS with XQuartz, I have seen `Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated` and upon digging further, `/opt/X11/bin/xauth:  timeout in locking authority file /var/folders/..../xauthfile` .

Answer (score 3):

At the [present time it seems you can't](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/ssh/clientloop.c?rev=1.256;content-type=text%2Fplain) **reliably** disable the time out **completely**. Nevertheless the patch needed shouldn't be too much intrusive so if you are able to update/recompile your `ssh` there should be a way out of it. You might want to watch this [question on the upstream mailing list](https://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2014-January/031943.html) for possible replies.