# SSH & ForwardX11 vs ForwardX11Trusted --> beyond my grasp

Tags: ssh, xforwarding

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 and trying to get my head around `ForwardX11` vs `ForwardX11Trusted`.

My default ssh_config contains the following lines:

```
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

Further, `man ssh_config` tells me that:

```
1.   command-line options
2.   user's configuration file (~/.ssh/config)
3.   system-wide configuration file (/etc/ssh/ssh_config)
```

and that `ForwardX11.default == no` and `ForwardX11Trusted.default == yes`.

Now my questions:

1. I take it that 1. takes precedence over 2. over 3. None is specified, thus the default settings should be applied, i.e. `ForwardX11Trusted == yes`. If I SSH into a remote machine without the `-Y` or `-X` option, X11 forwarding does not work.
2. If I specify `-X`, X11 forwarding works but it seems to be in trusted mode?
3. If I set

   ```
   ForwardX11 no
   ForwardX11Trusted no
   ```

   in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, I can now choose the mode correctly with the `-X` and `-Y` command line options. But, while the forwarding causes roughly .5 MBit of traffic in `-Y` mode, it hogs 6-10 MBit in `-X` mode.
4. If I explicitly set

   ```
   ForwardX11 yes
   ```

   SSH still ignores the `ssh_config` file. I still need to specify `ssh -X [...]`.
5. Why does SSH seem to ignore both the default settings and the config file?

Comment: Some answers in related question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107547/disable-forwardx11timeout-without-forwardx11trusted-in-openssh-client . The bonus question about X11 forwarding wasting hundreds of kilobit/sec of network traffic is interesting - may be worth asking separately?

Answer (score 21):

Per #4, are you editing the right file?  The `~/.ssh/config` file to change is the one on the client (where the keyboard is, usually).

As for #2 (and 3), remember that **ForwardX11Trusted** doesn't imply **ForwardX11**.  **ForwardX11Trusted** just means that if you turn on forwarding (whether via config file or command line) then the forwarded connection will be trusted.

Comment: So what is the difference between Trusted and non-Trusted modes?

Comment: Hmm, you original question indicates you read the man page, so you've seen the description of ForwardX11Trusted in ssh_config(5).  Perhaps it will help to understand that a trusted X11 client application has access to more than just its window; it can affect the whole X11 server and read data belonging to other windows.  Consider xdpyinfo or xkill, for example.  I consider the distinction bogus, though; I've never been able to use X11 except with ForwardX11Trusted=yes.  The distinction is relatively recent and IMO immature.

Answer (score 9):

I found this page useful:
https://padraic2112.wordpress.com/2007/07/09/bad-security-201-remote-x-sessions-over-ssh/

It basically answers your question #2:

> If ForwardX11Trusted is set to “yes”, then the commands ssh -X and ssh -Y are functionally equivalent. If ForwardX11 and ForwardX11Trusted are both set to “yes”, then the command flags are not only equivalent, they’re unnecessary… that is
>
> ```
> ssh user@host command = ssh -X user@host command = ssh -Y user@host command
> ```
>
> If ForwardX11 is set to “yes” and ForwardX11Trusted is set to “no”, then
>
> ```
> ssh user@host command = ssh -X user@host command =/= ssh -Y user@host command
> ```

Unfortunately, I have no insight on your other observations.