# $HOME readonly: /usr/bin/xauth: timeout in locking authority file /home/fooftp/.Xauthority

Tags: ssh, xforwarding, xauth

I get this message after a annoying timeout:

> ```
> /usr/bin/xauth:  timeout in locking authority file /home/fooftp/.Xauthority
> ```

For some reasons the `$HOME` directory is **not** writeable by the user.

I want this:

- leave the $HOME directory read-only even for the user.
- Keep `ForwardX11 yes` in `~/.ssh/config` for the client.
- No modifications at client side.
- No timeout if I connect to the machine. Hint: I don't need `ForwardX11` on this account.

Is there a way to disable `ForwardX11` for one account on the server side?

Other solutions are welcome.

Please ask if you don't understand something, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of options here

1. Disable ForwardX11 on the server

   The man page for `sshd_config` shows that you can set `X11Forwarding no` in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. If you do this, don't forget to restart the `ssh` daemon (`service ssh restart` works for me).
2. Create the file `/home/fooftp/.Xauthority`

   If you create the file `/home/fooftp/.Xauthority` and make it writeable by the user account, then it can be locked so the error message goes away. This does not disable X11 Forwarding so may not be appropriate for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can allow X11 forwarding on the user account you are using on the server. Once enabled xauth will no longer reference .Xauthority, you may leave it or remove it.

~/.ssh/config:

```
Host *
    ForwardAgent yes
    ForwardX11 yes
    # If no may need ssh -X or -Y for forwarding.
    ForwardX11Trusted no
```

Comment: $HOME is readonly, I can't do `touch ~/.Xauthority`

Comment: I corrected the answer, thank you. You shouldn't get any errors whether .Xauthority is present or removed.

Comment: I think this configuration is not safe,     ForwardX11Trusted yes bypass the xhost command, i have tried with xhost - and with -X accept all clients.

Comment: I think it is OK, since I have a secure connection from login, but I see your point about trusted and set trusted to no. From this: "remember that ForwardX11Trusted doesn't imply ForwardX11. ForwardX11Trusted just means that if you turn on forwarding (whether via config file or command line) then the forwarded connection will be trusted."  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138417/ssh-forwardx11-vs-forwardx11trusted-beyond-my-grasp