# SSH X11 forwarding - Issues with copying, DISPLAY and the "@" symbol

Tags: ssh, x11, xforwarding

I'm using `ssh -X user@ip` to connect to an SSH server (on the LAN, 100mbit/s connection).

It works well, but there's three issues:

1. After some time (can't tell when exactly, a felt hour or so) when I would close a window and try to open another I get the error: `Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0` and I have to logout and back in to fix this.
2. I can not type `@`. I first thought it's a locale issue, but locales are generated properly. The keyboard layout is proper aswell and other things like `!")$(_?` work.
3. I can copy something on my PC and then paste it into the X11 forwarded window, but the other way around not so much. *Something* is copied (clipboard is overwritten) but it's not pastable (attempting to paste in some apps causes the app to be unresponsive for ~a minute).

I have `xauth` installed (both machines), I use default settings for X11 forwarding, server is `OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10+deb10u2, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019` debian XFCE4, client is `OpenSSH_8.2p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020` on arch GNOME3.

I tried `xclip -o` and `xsel -o -b` but both don't print anything and run until I `CTRL+C` them.

Copying an `@` on the PC and then pasting it into the server app works.

Edit:

(DE keyboard layout): `xev` on client and server show the same keycode, client's XLookupString gives `@` (40), on server `q` (71). The events/codes for the `Alt Gr` key I need to keep pressed for the `@` and everything else is identical on both. `xmodmap` gives the exact same result on both.

Checking sshd log indeed gave me something: `channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed`, which apparently is rather vague.

Server: `X.Org X Server 1.20.4`
Client: `X.Org X Server 1.20.8`

Verbosity gave me: `Rejected X11 connection after ForwardX11Timeout expired`

And searching that on the net gave me the fix. Setting `ForwardX11Timeout` to a high value fixed it. Setting it to unlimited is [apparently not possible yet](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107547/disable-forwardx11timeout-without-forwardx11trusted-in-openssh-client). Using `-Y` instead of `-X` would apparently fix this aswell but [seems less secure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35512/what-is-the-difference-between-ssh-y-trusted-x11-forwarding-and-ssh-x-u/35518) than the config option.

Answer (score 2):

1) So something network related stopped working. Look at the `sshd` logs on the remote computer for suspicious error messages. If you don't find anything, increase verbosity both for the `ssh` client and the `sshd` server (see man-pages on how to do that).

2) The remote X program connects to your local X server, but it will still use some remote settings. So it's not really about "locale", it's about keyboard X settings. Start `xev` via forwarding to see what happens when you type `@` locally (whatever key combinations you need to use in your locale for this, you didn't tell us). `xmodmap` via forwarding may also be helpful.

3) I have no idea what happens here, this needs debugging on the X protocol level.

Also check if the X server and libraries on both the local and the remote computer have reasonably close versions. If they don't, try to make them closer. The X wire protocol is pretty stable, but if you two hosts disagree on something in there, that could explain your problems.

The `ssh` versions shouldn't matter much, `ssh` is just forwarding the X protocol transparently.

Comment: Please see my edit. 1) has been fixed.

Comment: I am confused now on (2). So `xev` shows you get the keysym for `@`, but you still can't "type it"? *Where* exactly you cannot type it? Is it possible that this program (or these programs) use `Alt Gr` for something else?

Comment: No it shows the `@` only on the client, on the server (X11 forwarded window) it shows up as `q`. The keycode and everything else (including the modifier key parts) is identical.

Comment: What does `setxkbmap -query` show on the local host, and on the remote host? If you need to debug more details, use `setxkbmap -print | xkbcomp - - > xxx.xkm` on both, and compare the results wrt. to `@` via `xkbcomp xxx.xkm`.

Comment: If I run this on the ssh server I get `XKB extension not present on localhost:11.0` for both comands. Might that be causing the issues? Just in case, I've tried to not only run it within the ssh session but also within a terminal started on the remote host using X11 forwarding, but same message.

Comment: Huh, 1.20 without XKB? That's unusual. I am running here Debian (well, Devuan) with 1.20, and it definitely has XKB. And please make sure to run it for the local side as well (no ssh forwarding).